# Infinite Scroll on Drupal 7 with AJAX

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I am trying to create an Infinite Scroll system to display past events on a page.
What I want is, when the top of the page is reached, I want to load past events.

I created the following JQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.main = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {

            // div scroll event
            $('#events-list .content').on('scroll', function() {
                var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
                // if div reaches top
                if (pos == 0) {
                    // some ajax to load past events
                    console.log('top');
                }
             });
    }}
})(jQuery);
```

How would you do to load past events with AJAX using my code?
If anyone could give a hint to the right direction or a link to some documentation that would be awesome!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make your question's title more specific/